# Guide for creating ASP.NET MVC RESTful API on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, azure

I want to create a simple ASP.NET MVC RESTful API, but I want to create it on Azure.

Any recommendations, tips & tricks, or examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look out for this book: [Building RESTful Web Applications with Microsoft Azure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470748834) when it is released.

Answer (score 1):

Also [Effective REST Services via .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321613252) has a great section on REST with Azure.